# Javascript working in chrome, not firefox or ie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to javascript/jquery. Have written the following script, it works in Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m, but not in Firefox 42.0 or IE 11.
Values in the format `%<value_name>%` are predefined values from the content management system that I am using.

The script is supposed to hide a button if the boolean value `"%asset_metadata_register_button%"` is set to `0`, or for one day after Date variable `"eventDate"` has taken place. Otherwise show the Button.

The script also is supposed to change the text and `href` value of the button after `eventDate` has taken place.

**HTML**

```
<p id="show"><a id="change" class="button" href="firstURl">Register</a></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Boolean value from Show Registration Button metadata field
    var number = "%asset_metadata_register_button%";

    // variable for start date of event
    var eventDate = new Date('%asset_attribute_start_date%');

    // variable for date at present time
    var now = new Date();

    // variable for one day after present time
    var oneDay = new Date('%asset_attribute_start_date%');

    oneDay.setDate(oneDay.getDate() + 1);

    // Hide button if Show Registration Button metadata field is set to no, or for one day after Webinar took place. Otherwise show Button.
    if (number == 1) {
        if (eventDate < now && now < oneDay) {
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "(Webinar will be uploaded shortly)";
        } else {
            $('#show').show();
        }
    } else {
        $('#show').hide();
    }

    // changes button text and link after webinar commences
    if (eventDate > now) {
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "View Webinar";
        document.getElementById("change").href = "secondURL";
    }
});
```

Comment: what format does the date `%asset_attribute_start_date%` have - my guess is that it's a date string format only chrome understands

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply ... its ISO8601 format, prints to screen like this 2015-11-04 01:30:00

Comment: if the input string is `2015-11-04 01:30:00` then firefox wont be able to parse it, and you end up with an `Invalid Date`

Comment: When you say it's "not working", what does it do? What errors do you see on the page or in the console?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example ?

Answer (score 0):

As +Jaromanda X mentioned you get an error with certain browsers.

Where your code looks like this:

```
// variable for start date of event
var eventDate = new Date('%asset_attribute_start_date%');

// variable for date at present time
var now = new Date();

//variable for one day after present time
var oneDay = new Date('%asset_attribute_start_date%');

oneDay.setDate(oneDay.getDate() + 1);
```

You can replace it with this:

```
var dateTime = '%asset_attribute_start_date%';
var date = dateTime.substring(0, dateTime.indexOf(" "));
var time = dateTime.substring(dateTime.indexOf(" ")+1);

date = date.substring(date.indexOf("-")+1) + "-" + date.substring(0, date.indexOf("-"));

var eventDate = new Date(date + ' ' + time);
var oneDay = new Date();
oneDay.setDate(eventDate.getDate() + 1);

var now = new Date();
```

What it does is replace the date format from '2015-11-04' to '11-04-2015'.